# I need to change thousands of External Links - any suggestions?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a database of about 20,000 products, each of which has an embedded, linked OLE object.  The linked file for each of these resides on our fileserver.  For reasons that I can 't control, these files are being moved!  So, I need to do one of two things.  Either re-embed and link all these files, using LotusScript, or find a way of programatically editing the External Link data.

Each of these methods has its own problems.  The first suffers the problem that for the OLE file to display properly, I need to open each product document in edit mode, click a button and resave it.  I can do this with an AutoHotKey script, but it's going to take a day or two to go through them all.

Or, I can find a way of accessing the External Link information programatically.  It's not available in LotusScript, and I can't find it using DXL.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to contact Ben Langhinrichs at Genii Software. He put up a few posts recently (I don't recall if it was on Facebook or on his blog) regarding OLE embedded objects. His Midas Rich Text API may be able to handle updating OLE links. It is commercial software, but Ben might even have sample code that cuts your work down so much that it could be worth it just for this one job.

Another approach that might work without any commercial software is DXL export, modfiying the link in the DXL, and then re-importing. (There's always some possibility of fidelity loss if you have other things in the document that DXL doesn't handle well, but my understanding is that it's much better now than it used to be.)

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I've exported the DXL and gone over it with a fine-tooth comb, but there's no plain text tag.  The link seems to be encoded in the OLE object itself.  I'm planning to have another look there tonight and see if I can pull something out.

I know Ben's name well, having seen it all over the Notes world for God knows how many years.  I'd like to try not to buy something, but I'll have a look at his site(s) and see what I can find.

Answer (score 2):

DXL exporter doesn't understand the binary contents of the OLE link -- it just dumps the data. You, however, could add code to interpret the base64 binary. I don't know how it's formatted, but OLE is a documented format, and you can also find tools online to convert base64 to binary and/or text that you can examine, to help you figure out what's stored where.

Or you can call Ben!

Comment: Years ago I tried to figure out the clipboard format for a doclink, and I ran into an OLE brick wall. I recall finding some documentation on OLE formats, but not much.  Maybe I gave up too easily.

Comment: In the past I've managed to extract the GIF from an OLE object using DXL and base64 decoding.  It was ugly, but it worked.  I'll see if I can find anything in OLE link format documentation though, before I run my script that is essentially doing it manually by sending keystrokes.  I have a spare PC that can do that for a few days :-)